# Snowflake - SP returning 0 on count when should be returning 1

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

i have the next two procedures in snowflake:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE db.schema.sp_test_1()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS
$$
DECLARE
    db_name varchar(20) DEFAULT 'DB1';
    schema_name varchar(30) DEFAULT 'SCHEMA1';
    table_name varchar(50);
    col_name varchar(60);
    response integer;
BEGIN
  table_name := 'TABLE1';
  col_name := 'COL1';
  response := (call sp_test_2(:db_name,:schema_name,:table_name,:col_name));
RETURN response;
END;
$$;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE db.schema.sp_test_2(db_na VARCHAR, schema_na VARCHAR, table_na VARCHAR, col_na VARCHAR)
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
  DECLARE
    value INTEGER;
    res1 resultset DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM "INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."COLUMNS" WHERE "TABLE_CATALOG" = :db_na AND "TABLE_SCHEMA" = :schema_na AND "TABLE_NAME" = :table_na AND "COLUMN_NAME" = :col_na);
    c1 CURSOR FOR res1;
  BEGIN
      FOR row_variable IN c1 DO
          value := row_variable.count;
      end for;
    RETURN value;
  END;
$$;
```

If i execute the select count outside of the sp, returns 1 row with the value 1 (column already exists in the table) but when i call the first sp: call db.schema.sp_test_1(); it returns 0.

I have tried a bunch of different thinks but nothing works, i tried identifier(:db_na) etc. but doesn't work!

Help please, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In db.schema.sp_test_2(), change the line

```
  res1 resultset DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM "INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."COLUMNS" WHERE "TABLE_CATALOG" = :db_na AND "TABLE_SCHEMA" = :schema_na AND "TABLE_NAME" = :table_na AND "COLUMN_NAME" = :col_na);
```

to

```
view_na varchar DEFAULT CONCAT(:db_na,'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS');
res1 resultset DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM IDENTIFIER(:view_na) WHERE "TABLE_CATALOG" = :db_na AND "TABLE_SCHEMA" = :schema_na AND "TABLE_NAME" = :table_na AND "COLUMN_NAME" = :col_na);
```

Answer (score 0):

In db.schema.sp_test_1(),
change the line

```
respuesta := (call sp_test_2(:db_name,:schema_name,:table_name,:col_name));
```

to

```
response := (call sp_test_2(:db_name,:schema_name,:table_name,:col_name));
```

The view "INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."COLUMNS" would return results only when the role has privilege on that object/table that you are trying to fetch the details about.

So, check if the owner of the stored procedure has 'select' privilege or 'ownership' privilege on the table DB1.SCHEMA1.TABLE1;

```
show grants on table DB1.SCHEMA1.TABLE1;
```

Note: A stored procedure runs with either the caller’s rights or the owner’s rights. The default is owner’s rights.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-rights

Comment: Hi Uma, yeah sorry thats a problem only here because i translate my spanish procedure to english, but in fact that line its ok in my code. The grants on the role thats is a thing that i'm gonna to validate but the respuesta/response error is just a thing on the translation that i made here is not a problem in the actual code

Comment: i've already check the grants and the role that i'm using has the OWNERSHIP privilege on the table

Comment: I check the select count(*) statement without the where clause and is working fine, the problem is when trying to filter a special db, schema, table and column.. idk

Comment: yes, if i change the: SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM "INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."COLUMNS" WHERE "TABLE_CATALOG" = :db_na AND "TABLE_SCHEMA" = :schema_na AND "TABLE_NAME" = :table_na AND "COLUMN_NAME" = :col_na          for        SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM "INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."COLUMNS"     works fine but adding the where clause is when isn't returning anything

Comment: You have to prefix the information_schema.columns with the database name as below:
    view_na varchar DEFAULT CONCAT(:db_na,'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS');
    res1 resultset DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM IDENTIFIER(:view_na) WHERE "TABLE_CATALOG" = :db_na AND "TABLE_SCHEMA" = :schema_na AND "TABLE_NAME" = :table_na AND "COLUMN_NAME" = :col_na);